# Tag system like Quora?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, tags, archives

What would be the best way to go for creating a tag-system similar to the one on quora.com?

If you don't know what quora looks like, here is what I'm thinking about:

On the tag archive page the user can add or edit a description of the tag and tie a photo to the tag.

The tag also have a manage page on the frontend were it's possible to delete the tag or merge it with another one if it's a duplicate.

All of this is made from the frontend.

How hard would it be to achieve this? How would one do?

Comment: I don't know quora: Can every user add a photo and do a description on it's own, or is this shared across all users?

Answer (score 1):

The [Matt's Community Tags (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/matts-community-tags/) might contain some code that is of use for what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I have a plugin for merging tags, but from the back-end:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-management-tools/